# Number of records in the result causes -> Object reference not set to an instance of an object - Azure Cosmos Db

Tags: java, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I'm getting the below error when retrieving data from cosmos db using java.

```
com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 1 and error message '[ActivityId=92f973a7-c33f-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx] 
Error=1, Details='Response status code does not indicate success: InternalServerError (500); 
Substatus: 0; ActivityId: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000; 
Reason: (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.);' on server xxxx-xxxx-westus.mongo.cosmos.azure.com:10255
```

Below is the method used to get data.

```
public List<T> getData(String orKey,
                          String[] orValues,
                          LinkedHashMap<String, Object> andProperties,
                          String orderByKey, int offset, int limit) {

Bson[] orFilers = new Bson[orValues.length];
int counter = 0;
if (orValues.length > 0) {
  for (String s : orValues) {
    orFilers[counter++] = eq(orKey, s.trim());
  }
}

Bson[] andFilers = new Bson[andProperties.size()];
counter = 0;
if (andProperties.size() > 0) {
  for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : andProperties.entrySet()) {
    andFilers[counter++] = eq(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
  }
}

ArrayList<T> results = new ArrayList<>();
collection.find(and(or(orFilers), and(andFilers)))
        .skip(offset)
        .limit(limit)
        .sort(descending(orderByKey))
        .forEach((Consumer<T>) t -> {
          results.add(t);
        });
return results;
```

}

I did some debugging and found out when the `results` list has 102 or more records this error occurs. I found it by changing the `limit` and `offset` values.

when,

```
offset = 0 & limit = 101 => success
offset = 0 & limit = 102 => error
offset = 1 & limit = 102 => error
offset = 1 & limit = 105 => error
offset = 1 & limit = 101 => success
```

*Note: There are 113 valid records for the given query.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was on the index field. I had created an index with the Date type field and some of the records had null value for that field.

```
public void createIndex(String keyString) {
    Document key = new Document(keyString, 1);
    this.collection.createIndex(key, new IndexOptions());
}
```

Changed that to a long type field and the issue got resolved. Why the earlier query gives error on 102 count is something that I couldn't find.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the **`MaxItemCount`** count value?

For pagination with Cosmosdb , the default value is 100.

> You can specify the maximum number of items returned by a query by
> setting the MaxItemCount. The MaxItemCount is specified per request
> and tells the query engine will to return that number of items or
> fewer. You can set MaxItemCount to -1 if you don't want to place a
> limit on the number of results per query execution.

You can set the maxItemCount  and try to execute again .